# TV mounting with long reach

Tags: product-recommendation, mounting, home-theater

I'm looking to mount my LCD TV (26" Sony Bravia) in an alcove next to a chimney breast. I'd we view the TV from the other side of the chimney breast, so the mounting will need to allow the TV to come out from the wall far enough that we can rotate it 90 degrees such that it's at right angles to the wall of the alcove and viewable at the other end of the room. Plenty of TV mounts appear to offer the articulation to do this, but I'm having difficulty finding a mount that will allow the TV to come out far enough for it to fully rotate the 90 degrees without touching the chimney breast. By my calculations the reach needed is around 59cm. Can anyone recommend a mount with this kind of reach, or, failing that, an alternative mounting approach that might achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good experience with large articulating mounts from monoprice.com.  And they're pretty inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a google. I can't recommend it as such; never seen it before. But [here's](http://www.freeshipmounts.com/products/EXTRA-LONG-ARM-FULL-MOTION-MOUNT-FOR-TV-SCREEN-SIZES-10%252d37%22-%28Model-FSMLCD982a%29.html) what I found.